# Select customers with no invoices after date

Tags: mysql

I have **Client** and **Invoice** tables. They have **one-to-many** relationship, where `Client.id = Invoice.client_id`.

**Client columns**:

- id

**Invoice columns**:

- id,
- client_id,
- invoice_date

Of course the example is simplified to relevant data.

**I am trying to** select customers who did **NOT** have invoices after '2010-01-01'.

I can't figure out any working way to do this. Some routes I took look like this (there many other variations, but no point displaying the here):

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(i.invoice_date > "2010-01-01") AS cnt 
 FROM Client AS c LEFT JOIN Invoice i ON i.client_id = c.id 
 GROUP BY c.id HAVING cnt = 0
```

and

```
SELECT client_id, COUNT(invoice_date > '2010-01-01') as cnt 
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY client_id HAVING cnt = 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a sub-query with [`NOT EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Client
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Invoice 
  WHERE Invoice.invoice_date > '2010-01-01' AND Invoice.client_id = Client.id
)
```

You can also use `SUM` with [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) or [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
-- CASE
SELECT c.id, SUM(CASE WHEN i.invoice_date > '2010-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt 
FROM Client AS c LEFT JOIN Invoice i ON i.client_id = c.id 
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING cnt = 0

-- IF
SELECT c.id, SUM(IF(i.invoice_date > '2010-01-01', 1, 0)) AS cnt 
FROM Client AS c LEFT JOIN Invoice i ON i.client_id = c.id 
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING cnt = 0
```

You can also use `COUNT`, but with [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) or [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
-- CASE
SELECT client_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN invoice_date > '2010-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as cnt 
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY client_id HAVING cnt = 0

-- IF
SELECT client_id, COUNT(IF(invoice_date > '2010-01-01', 1, NULL)) as cnt 
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY client_id HAVING cnt = 0
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b99f404778108b40ce0009b7baf0e6e)

Comment: I was under an impression that `NOT EXISTS` was quite an inefficient method. Also, rather than `COUNT` which is also inefficient, use `SUM` as you have illustrated.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `NOT IN` with a sub-query

```
SELECT * FROM client 
WHERE id NOT IN (
     SELECT client_id 
     FROM invoice
     WHERE invoice_date>'2020-01-01'
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :-

```
    Select Client.* from Client Client left join Invoice Invoice on 
    client.id = Invoice.client_id and Invoice.invoice_date > "2010-01-01" 
    where Invoice.client_id is null;
```

Basically you include only the subset of the data after "2010-01-01" from the invoice table.